# Apache Spark Driver hangs when DataFrame broadcast fails due to OutOfMemoryError

Tags: multithreading, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I tried to broadcast a DataFrame which turned out to be larger than `spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold`, and the driver logged

```
Exception in thread "broadcast-exchange-0" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError Not enough memory to build and broadcast the table to all worker nodes. As a workaround, you can...
```

However, instead of returning to `Driver` thread and fail, the app just hangs and the driver is stuck at:

```
sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1037)
java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.tryAcquireSharedNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1328)
scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryAwait(Promise.scala:208)
scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:218)
scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.result(Promise.scala:223)
org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResult(ThreadUtils.scala:201)
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.BroadcastExchangeExec.doExecuteBroadcast(BroadcastExchangeExec.scala:136)
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.InputAdapter.doExecuteBroadcast(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:367)
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeBroadcast$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:144)
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeBroadcast$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:140)
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
...
...
```

`spark.sql.broadcastTimeout` is set to a quite high number due to other historic issues we had, and indeed the driver failed on timeout eventually,  but still I wonder if this is the expected behavior? I tried to get my head around `ThreadUtils.awaitResult` but I can't find evidence that this is behavior is (explicitly) expected.

Can anyone confirm this is not a bug?

Comment: what is the alue of `spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold` what are other parameters in spark submit. its quite evident huge chunk its not able to broadcast

Comment: Does that really matter? I don't mind that the data is too large to broadcast, I only ask why the driver thread waits for broadcastTimeout before it fails. I would expect it to fail fast.

Comment: there is 2G limit for broadcast i believe